# Copy all excel rows into one row

Tags: excel-formula

How can I copy all rows into one row? Not concatenate the cells. I have a big table with multiple data rows and want them all to be on a single row without having to copy paste (there are about 800 rows and 10 columns).

For example I have a table with two rows, 2 values each row such as:

**row A1:** m, n

**row B1:** x, y

I want it to become 1 single row with 4 values in it (each value in a column):

**row A1:** m, n, x, y

Thank you.

Comment: your example gives an impression that, you want to merge columns & keep all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't concatenate, in concept, what you're asking to do?
I have a somewhat similar scenario where I often combine all data into one long string.
If you have column A with data in rows 1 and 2:
m, n
x, y

In cell B1 for example (the same row as the first row of data), you could enter the formula "=A1". In cell B2, you could enter a formula to create the text equivalent of a running total. Choose your delimiter, such as a space, comma, or a space+comma.  So, in cell B2, you could enter the formula "=B1&", "&A2". This says, "take what is in the cell above me (which is the same as the first entry) and add the value of the next row entry." Once you do this second formula, you can copy this formula down (using auto-fill) your entire list (e.g., 800 rows).
If you need 1 row but still need 10 separate columns, you simply do this formula 10 times (once for each column). Once you've done all the formulas, go down to the last row, copy - paste special - values, and you will have your data. You can then delete your 800 (or however many) rows.
Let me know if this does NOT make sense.

Comment: I noticed my formatting didn't work as I wanted for my example:

Comment: row 1: m, n and row 2: x, y

Comment: But I don't want to combine data into one long string, that's why I mentioned not concatenate. I want my final result to be a single row with 4 columns.

Comment: you'd be concatenating (combining) the row data but not the column data. You should do a formula for each column you're keeping separate, whether it's 4 columns or 10.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it's more complex than I imagined. I have to use a formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,((ROW()-1)*5)+(FLOOR(COLUMN()-1,4)/4),(COLUMN()-1)-(FLOOR(COLUMN()-1,4)))
```

Here's the link:
[Copy all rows into one row](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1171-convert-multiple-rows-to-single-row.html#a1)